# `npm start` failed after `npm run eject`

Tags: react-native

Command `start` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `react-native start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ishan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-24T11_24_50_101Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `start` script in your `package.json`

Your `package.json` must have a `start` script like so -

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "start": "react-native-scripts start"
  }
}
```